# Visual studio forms designer does not revert to default pointer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I have a strange issue with visual studio (2015) forms designer. After a control drop, it's still this control which is affected to my pointer and visual studio does not revert to the default pointer, sometimes keypress on escape works et revert to the default one, sometimes it doesn't (I have to select Pointer in toolbox). It's not a big issue but it's annoying on long term. Is there any fix or configuration for it ?

Comment: didnt get you. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: It is the kind of mishap that can be explained when the control burns 100% core after it is dropped, usually by executing the same event handler over and over again.  Diagnose with Task Manager, Processes tab, CPU column for devenv.exe.  Otherwise entirely too vague to guess why this happened.

Comment: Exactly it seems that my cpu is struggled with control drop...